# RAM recognition in windows 10

Tags: memory, sodimm

I have 2 ram slots, both with active memory cards fitted.(I have 2GB in slot one and 4GB in slot 2)

Both slots are recognised in BIOS, and it reads the 4gb memory in slot 2

In Systems>Settings>About it is only stating 2GB of ram installed.
In Task Manager>Performance>Memory it also gives a result of 1.9 GB and states "Slots used: 1 of 2"

I have a asus vivo pc VM-42

Comment: How do you know it doesn’t recognize slot 2?

Comment: Am not sure if it does or not. In Systems>Settings>About it is only stating 2GB of ram installed. (I have 2GB in slot one and 4GB in slot 2) In Task Manager>Performance>Memory it also gives a result of 1.9 GB and "Slots used: 1 of 2" ....

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having then. Don’t post it in a comment. Instead [edit] your question to improve the quality.

Comment: apologies, I hit enter for a new line and posted the last comment before I had finished writing!

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer or motherboard? Again, please [edit] your question to include the information you have provided in comments.

Comment: Windows isn’t concerned with detecting memory modules or anything. It just takes what is handed to it by the firmware. So, if anything, you’re looking at a BIOS/UEFI bug.

Comment: Do I need to adjust the settings in BIOS?

Comment: It might be detected by the BIOS but not used by Windows if it is bad. Try running the system with the single 4Gb chip. Is this new memory? Original memory? Etc.

Comment: Used memory (though tested apparently) Tried running the single 4gb - System won't even power on!

Comment: It might not work with your hardware, or it's broken (if you carried a static charge, one touch was enough to wreck it)

Comment: The memory is either bad or incompatible with your computer.

Comment: Yes, the store did say they were out of anti-static bags so will return. For future reference, how do I ensure I don't carry a static charge?

Comment: Got a new compatible 2gb Crucial Ram - Still having the same issue! BIOS recognises but not Windows.